# NightmareJS is not showing anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

Im trying to execute the example from https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare but it doesnt return anything

---

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "new_nightmare",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nightmare": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

---

### index.js

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

console.log('before')
nightmare
    .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
    .type('#search_form_input_homepage', 'github nightmare')
    .click('#search_button_homepage')
    .wait('#r1-0 a.result__a')
    .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#r1-0 a.result__a').href)
    .end()
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log('Result ->', result)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Search failed:', error)
    })
console.log('after')
```

---

### output

[image]

Comment: Can you share On which OS you are running this script and how are you running the command?

Comment: You can use: `DEBUG=nightmare node index.js` to see what happened in process